# Is it possible to retrieve data which is on the long process in Opencl kernel execution?

Tags: opencl

I have a Opencl kernel code which should be run on the GPU. It has a loop that do the operation continuously and modify an array. Is there any way to access the array during it's long modification to see it's progressive result?

The execution may takes hours time. I want to produce a graphic result from the array each 30 seconds. I currently have to wait and when the final result completed I produce that graphical result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should *not* make a kernel which runs for hours. For one thing, if the GPU is the same one that your display is connected to, your display and GUI won't update. Under Windows (and likely other OSs) the driver will reset the GPU after a few seconds of a kernel running. The only case where this is possible is with compute-only devices (like NVIDIA Tesla in a special mode). However, without OpenCL 2.0 and fine-grained SVM there is no way for the CPU to get partial results.

Instead, you should break up your work into many small kernel executions. This will also solve your problem of data access; you can target a ring buffer of output buffers so the CPU can look at the results of one while the next kernel is producing the next set of results.